# Spectral radius of the Volterra operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, spectral-radius

The Volterra operator acting on $L^2[0,1]$ is defined by $$A(f)(x)=\int_0^x f(t) dt$$ 
How can I calculate the spectral radius of $A$ using the spectral radius formula for bounded linear operators: $$\rho(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \|A^n\|^{1/n} \text{?}$$
This was given as an exercise in a book right after introducing the spectral radius formula, so it should be simple exercise, but I don't see immediately how to do the calculations. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210888/iterated-integrals-and-riemann-liouville-fractional-derivatives/210895#210895) is how to find $A^n(f)(x).$

Comment: Please what is the name of the book?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint 1.** Prove by induction that
$$
A^n(f)(x)=\int\limits_0^x f(s)\frac{(x-s)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}ds\tag{1}
$$
**Hint 2.** Given $(1)$ show that 
$$
\Vert A^n\Vert\leq\frac{1}{(n-1)!}
$$
**Hint 3.** To compute $\rho(A)$ recall the following Stirling's approximation
$$
N!\approx\left(\frac{N}{e}\right)^N\sqrt{2\pi N}
$$

Comment: So is it correct that the spectral radius is $0$?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Norbert please have you an example about how to caculate the spectral radius of a nonlinear operator ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou, no I don't

Comment: In **Hint** **2**, can't we show that $\|A^{n}\|\leq\frac{1}{n!}$, which immediately follows from **(1)**?

Answer (score 10):

Below I will try to follow Norbert's hints:

**Hint 1.**

Let's go from $n=2$ to $n=3$ to check the formula.

$$A^2f(x)=\int_0^x f(s)(x-s) ds$$

Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
A^3f(x) &=& \int_0^x\int_0^tf(s)(t-s)ds dt\\
&=&\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \chi_{[0,x]}(t)\chi_{[0,t]}(s)f(s)(t-s) ds dt \\
&\stackrel{*}{=}& \int_0^1f(s)\chi_{[0,x]}(s)\int_0^1\chi_{[s,x]}(t)(t-s)dt ds\\
&=& \int_0^xf(s)(\frac{x^2}{2}-sx+\frac{s^2}{2})ds \\
&=&\int_0^xf(s)\frac{(x-s)^2}{2}ds 
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\chi_{B}(\cdot)$ is the characteristic function of a set $B$ and at * I have used $\chi_{[0,x]}(t)\chi_{[0,t]}(s)=\chi_{[0,x]}(s)\chi_{[s,x]}(t)$ and Fubini to exchange order of integrals.

**Hint 2.**

\begin{eqnarray*}
\|A^nf\|_2^2 &=& \int_0^1 \left| \int_0^x f(s) \frac{(x-s)^n}{(n-1)!}ds \right|^2 dx \\
&\leq& \left( \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \right)^2\|f\|_2^2
\end{eqnarray*}
since $|(x-s)^n|\leq 1$ for $s \in [0,x]$, $x \leq1$.

**Hint 3.**

$$\|A^n\|^{1/n}\leq \left( \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \right)^{1/n} \rightarrow 0$$
since $$(n-1)!^{1/n} \geq (\sqrt{2\pi})^{1/n}(n-1)^{1-\frac{1}{2n}}e^{-1+\frac{1}{n}}  \rightarrow \infty \text{.}$$
In this last step the following [lower bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is used: $$n! \geq \sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-n} $$

**Conclusion**

The spectral radius of the Volterra operator is $0$.