# Picard iteration (general)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

This a general question about Picard iterations and is as follows.

Let A be a $n\times n$ matrix. show that the Picard method for solving $X^{'}=AX$, $X(0)=X_{0}$
gives the solution $e^{tA}X_{0}$

I really don't even have a clue where to start? i have used it to do some very simple problems but im totally stumped on this one.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. The Picard iteration looks for a fixed point of the operator $(Tx)(t) = x_0 + A \int_0^t  x(\tau)  d \tau$. You could define a sequence $x_0(t) = x_0$ (slight abuse of notation), and $x_{n+1} = T x_n$ and show that it converges in some appropriate sense. Then expand the solution to show that it equals $e^{At} x_0$.

Comment: Im not sure what i mean eitheir that how its written in my textbook =) i think what you have stated above is what they want me to do.
Which makes some sense you using induction to show that eventually that will be the solution?

Comment: Do you know how the method works for a simple ode $y'(x)=ay(x)$?

Comment: Yes but that is it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a start,

$$ X_{n+1}(t) = X_0 + A \int_0^t  X_n(\tau)  d \tau$$

$$= X_0 +  \int_0^t A\left(X_0 + A \int_0^t  X_{n-1}(\tau)  d \tau  \right)  d \tau  $$

$$ = X_0 + AX_0 t + \int_{0}^{t}(t-\tau)A^2 X_{n-1}(\tau) d\tau $$

$$ = X_0 + AX_0 t + \int_{0}^{t}(t-\tau)A^2 \left(X_0 + A \int_0^t  X_{n-2}(\tau)  d \tau \right) d\tau $$

$$ = X_0 + AX_0 \,t +\int_{0}^{t}(t-\tau)A^2X_0 d\tau + \frac{1}{2!}\int_0^t (t-\tau)^2 A^3X_{n-2}(\tau)  d \tau   $$

$$ = X_0 + AX_0 \,t +A^2X_0 \frac{t^2}{2!}+ \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t (t-\tau)^2 A^3X_{n-2}(\tau)  d \tau = \ldots.  $$

I leave it here for you to finish the problem. Work out few other terms to see the pattern. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210888/iterated-integrals-and-riemann-liouville-fractional-derivatives) for the iterated integration.

Comment: wow that looks exactly like the $e^{At}$ expansion haha!

Tyvm i can finish it from here for sure.

Comment: This is a nice, intuitive explanation, but to show that this converges, you need some bounds on $X_n$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks for the cooment In my opinion, I think students need to learn how to compute things first, then they get exposed to advanced theory. Just like in the case of calculus and real analysis.

Comment: Is there a proof that we can actually apply picard iteration to matrices ? How do we know it's not just a trick? Thankss