# Picard Iteration: Convergence of system

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, picard-scheme

I want to prove that, for any $t$, a solution exists in the interval $[0,T]$, when $T>0$.

$x'(t)=A(t)x(t)$

My question is quite similar to this one [Picard iteration (general)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341997/picard-iteration-general/342050), but with one small difference. My $A(t)$ is a function of $t$, whereas in the other question $A$ seems to be constant.

Picard iteration: $x^{[k+1]}=x_0+\int^t_0A(τ)x^{[k]}(τ) dτ$. Where $x_0$ is arbitrary.

I want tor prove that $x^{[k+1]}$ converges on the given interval and that it satisfies the equation below.

$|x^{[k+1]}(t)-x^{[k]}(t)|\le |x_0| $$\frac{π^{k+1}(t)}{(k+1)!}$ where $π(t)=\int^t_0||A(τ)||dτ$.

I'm not sure how to account for the variant function $A(t)$ in my proof, so I was hoping someone could show me what it look like

Comment: The function $f(t,x)=A(t)x$ is Lipschitz in x on any domain where A is bounded, so you can follow the usual argument.

Comment: As said by @Lutzl, why do you ask once more a question (that you do not reference) moreover to which a seemingly satusfying answer has been given ? Besides, Picard method has a limited range of practical application.