# Changing order of integration (multiple integral)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Prove $$ \int_0^a\left( \int_0^x \left( \int_0^y \left( \int_0^z f(u) \, du \right) dz \right) dy \right) dx = \int_0^a \frac {(a-t)^3}{3!} f(t) dt $$ where $a$ is constant.

So I began with two most inner integrals i.e. the double integral

$$ \int_0^y \left( \int_0^z f(u) du \right) dz $$

We are doing this over $0 \leq u \leq z \leq y \leq x \leq a$. So we want

$$ \int_0^y \left( \int_0^z f(u) du \right) dz = \int_?^? \left( \int_?^? f(u) dz \right) du  $$

And immediately this problem got me stumped. How can one tell what the upper/lower bounds become? Keep in mind that drawing this region won't do much good as we are working in four dimensions.

EDIT: Forgot something crucial, edited now!

Comment: Is $f(u)$ given?

Comment: No it is not given.

Comment: Then I'm skeptical that this possibly can be true, considering the RHS doesn't contain $f(u)$ at all...

Comment: My bad I forgot to add essential information in the RHS, all taken care of now!

Answer (score 1):

Related techniques: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210888/iterated-integrals-and-riemann-liouville-fractional-derivatives/210895#210895). Here is an approach. Start writing the integral as

> $$ I = \int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{x}h(y)dydx. $$

then change the order of the integration which gives

> $$ I = \int_{0}^{a}\int_{y}^{a}h(y)dxdy= \int_{0}^{a} (a-y) h(y)dy\,. $$

Repeat the same technique and tackle the integral

> $$ I = \int_{0}^{a} (a-y) h(y)dy =  \int_{0}^{a} (a-y) \int_{0}^{y} g(z)dz dy $$

and change the order of integration. Continue the process and you will get the answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply but why avoid starting from the inner integral? also why is it ok to write $h(y)$ instead of all the inner integrals?

Comment: @user170817: I wrote $h(y)$ just to make it look less complicated for you then replace $h(y)$ by its integral representation.

Comment: right I get that but you seem confident about it being a function of y, how so? also again, do we not have to start from the inner most integrals? if not, why cant we? thanks for the help!

Comment: @user170817: Off course it is a function in $y$! Check the outer integral of $h(y)$. Try to go from in to out. As I said it is my approach to the problem.

Comment: ok thanks. but if I started from in to out, like I did in my post, what would then be the new limits?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{y}\int_{0}^{z}
\fermi\pars{u}\,\dd u\,\dd z \,\dd y\,\dd x}
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{a}
\fermi\pars{u}\Theta\pars{z - u}\Theta\pars{y - z}\Theta\pars{x - y}
\,\dd u\,\dd z\,\dd y\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{a}
\fermi\pars{u}\Theta\pars{z - u}\Theta\pars{y - z}\
\overbrace{\bracks{\int_{0}^{a}\Theta\pars{x - y}\,\dd x}}
^{\ds{=\ \color{#c00000}{a - y}}}\ \,\dd y\,\dd z\,\dd u 
\\[3mm]&=-\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{a}
\fermi\pars{u}\Theta\pars{z - u}\bracks{\int_{0}^{a}\pars{y - a}
\Theta\pars{y - z}\,\dd y}\,\dd z\,\dd u 
\\[3mm]&=-\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{a}
\fermi\pars{u}\Theta\pars{z - u}\bracks{\int_{z}^{a}\pars{y - a}
\,\dd y}\,\dd z\,\dd u 
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{a}
\fermi\pars{u}\Theta\pars{z - u}{\pars{z - a}^{2} \over 2}\,\dd z\,\dd u 
=\int_{0}^{a}\fermi\pars{u}\int_{u}^{a}{\pars{z - a}^{2} \over 2}\,\dd z\,\dd u 
\\[3mm]&=-\int_{0}^{a}\fermi\pars{u}{\pars{u - a}^{3} \over 3!}\,\dd u
=\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{a}{\pars{a - u}^{3} \over 3!}\fermi\pars{u}\,\dd u}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\Theta\pars{\xi}}$ is the [Heaviside Step Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ continuous. 
Put $\displaystyle F_1(z=\int_0^zf(u)du$. Then $F_1$ is the antiderivative of $f$ ( we have $F_1^{\prime}(z)=f(z)$)such that $F_1(0)=0$. Put $\displaystyle F_2(y)=\int_0^yF_1(z)dz$. Then by the same remark, we have $F_2^{\prime\prime}(y)=f(y)$, and $F_2(0)=F_2^{\prime}(0)=0$. We continue, and find that your integral $F(a)$ as function of $a$ is such that $F^{(4)}(a)=f(a)$ and $F^{(j)}(0)=0$ for $j=0,1,2,3$. Now use the Taylor formula:
$$F(a)=F(0)+aF^{\prime}(0)+F^{\prime\prime}(0)\frac{a^2}{2!}+F^{(3)}(0)\frac{a^3}{3!}+\int_0^a \frac{(a-t)^3}{3!}F^{(4)}(t)dt$$
Hence
$$F(a)=\int_0^a \frac{(a-t)^3}{3!}f(t)dt$$